# Does MongoDb $set operator in (non index field) will be expensive?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I have a collection which have multiple indexes, and often i have to push some data into an array of that collection. I have tried to go through MongoDb Doc, but the best i can get was,

> For inserts and updates to un-indexed fields, the overhead for sparse indexes is less than for non-sparse indexes. Also for non-sparse indexes, updates that do not change the record size have less indexing overhead.

I am aware of the difference of sparse indexes and non sparse indexes, and its makes sense that overhead for sparse indexes will be less.

**But why is it that, even when i am updating just a un-indexed field in my document, why all other index has to update ! Is it because every index has the same data and all the data has to be updated ?**

My Document

```
var sample = new Schema({
   ***
   student_list: [ {type :Schema.Types.Mixed}],
   location:  [ {type :Schema.Types.Mixed}],
   ****
});
student_list.studID will be indexed

{studID:1,city:M,Time:"... e}
```

Now i often have to update location field. Queries

```
db.sample.find({student_list.studID:"studid"})
db.sample.find({student_list.studID:"studid", student_list.city:"M"})
all using student_list_studId_1 index
```

Is this approach is fine or shall i create a diff collection and with every student list as a seperate doc, (every sample doc will have multiple student ids, which may be common across diff samples docs )

Comment: what version of mongo? and what type of storage engine do you use?

Comment: MLab free plan for now

Comment: Sandbox uses mongo 3.0.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why index is updated on every insert is connected with document size and its allocation.

Let's say that document has 1765 bytes, and we are adding next 950 bytes (data + bson overhead), that could execute a relocation of given document as it is not fitting in current allocated data block -> and db engine need to update pointers in all indexes to point to new document location.

Comment: Ohh now i get it thanks! 
Well than in my case which approach will be more wise ? having embedded document or seperate collection which will have reference to the main sample document